# Animal Crossing: Pocket Camp .zdat File

Tags: android, file-format, unpacking, decryption, deobfuscation

Hello I am trying to obtain the music from the new game Animal Crossing: Pocket Camp. The music is contained in files like these:

> https://download-cdn-ac-pocketcamp.akamaized.net/assets/c8nZd_d233535a9244b7238bb423cb4f3f1c6e7dccf686_dena/compass/Android/3c1c9e59/f3c14602/25238ae2/1899ac8d.zdat

They seem to be split up and saved locally, like this:

> https://mega.nz/#!Xk9wzByB!5WtbQQtBFdQtId0AgJWQx2vIQuj5XUBAL9CD4b3t34Y

Although the split up files contain no header, you can see the FSB5 headers inside both, which means they contain music. Although no program I've tested knows how to extract or convert these.

The files do not look encrypted. But cutting out the FSB's do not produce anything valid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The file does not appear to be obfuscated or encrypted in any way. The header appears to be trivial. I have included a description of the header for the `.zdata` you posted. The `.unity3d` files contained within are the typical Unit3d webpack files. You can google around for a depacker for those, there are several.

[image: example]

Comment: If a webpack is what I'm thinking, it doesn't look like one. As there's no header like "UnityFS". Could you link to an extractor that works because none seem to on the split up file that was saved by the game.